# JQuery to load div after page is completely loaded is not working in Chrome, but is in Safari and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm using the code below (JQuery) to delay the loading of a div until after the **entire** page has loaded (code, images, etc and rendered). It is working in Safari and Firefox, but not in Chrome. On Safari and Firefox, the web page loads and renders everything, and then it loads the div (the Facebook embed) after the browser says everything is loaded (loader stops spinning, page content is shown, browsers developer tools say everything is loaded -- not just DOM). In Chrome, though, it just loads at the end (after DOM content) but before everything is loaded and shown (like it does in Safari and Firefox, which is how it is supposed to and how I want it to work). I would greatly appreciate any help on making this work in Chrome like it does in the other browsers! (I asked yesterday, but the answer I was provided didn't fix the issue for me, and I perhaps wasn't clear about what I wanted (perhaps mistaken for only after DOM was loaded) so I decided to put it up again so it was more clear.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function insertFB(){
var html='<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/bobcaputolivingwell" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/bobcaputolivingwell"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/bobcaputolivingwell">Bob Caputo Living Well</a></blockquote></div></div>';
$("#FB_PAGE").html(html);
}

if (document.addEventListener){
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", insertFB, false);
}   

if (/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
var _timer = setInterval(function(){
if(/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)){
insertFB;
}
},10);
}  

window.onload = insertFB();  

</script>
```

Comment: I am not a huge JavaScript expert, but I don't think the assignment to window.onload is correct. It should be: window.onload = insertFB.
The way you're doing, you're calling insertFB at the time of the assignment. Am I wrong?

Comment: All you need is one load event and assign the handler as opposed to tests like `document.addEventListener`, `/WebKit/i.test...` etc.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox somebody else mentioned this to me, so you're probably not wrong. Just for some reason, with that code, when you remove the parentheses on window.onload it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're essentially triggering that function 3 times in browsers such as Chrome/Safari. All you need is the following.

```
function insertFB() {
    var html = '<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/bobcaputolivingwell" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/bobcaputolivingwell"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/bobcaputolivingwell">Bob Caputo Living Well</a></blockquote></div></div>';
    $("#FB_PAGE").html(html);
}

$(window).on("load", insertFB);
```

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for your reply. I had a friend make the code for me, and yours is doing the same thing but with less code and quicker because it has to do less stuff (presumably) :). The only problem is...on Chrome, it's still not working (Firefox and Safari are indeed working correctly)... Do you have any additional suggestions? I'd be happy to give you the website URL. Thank you so much in advance, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with jQuery -

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var html = '<div class="fb-page">Page Loaded.</div>';

            $(window).load(function() {
                $("#FB-PAGE").html(html);
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="FB-PAGE"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for responding. This didn't work until I changed the "#FB_PAGE" to "#fb-page", but, like the answer below this one...it worked in Safari and Firefox (and is much shorter, simpler, and probably even quicker than what I had before, so thank you!), but it still didn't work in Chrome. Do you have any additional suggestions? Let me know. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please scratch that part of where I changed the "#FB_PAGE" to "#fb-page" to make it work, I was mistaken and confused :) -- but the Chrome thing still applies. Thanks, Jared.

Comment: Wait...please do disregard what I said about disregarding changing "#FB_PAGE" to "#fb-page"...turns out when it is "#FB_PAGE" it doesn't display (it only displays an ellipsis), but when it is "#fb-page" it does display in all browsers, and like I said before, in Safari and Firefox the loading works as intended, but not in Chrome. Thanks again and sorry for the confusion, I appreciate any further input :).

Comment: Actually, this answer has been deprecated since jQuery 1.8, Ishettyl's is correct. @Jared Caputo https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to use the "load" event. DOMContentLoaded is supposed to fire when the DOM is ready but before assets have loaded. See the description of DOMContentLoaded from [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded):

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has
>   been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets,
>   images, and subframes to finish loading. A very different event - load
>   - should be used only to detect a fully-loaded page. It is an incredibly popular mistake to use load where DOMContentLoaded would be
>   much more appropriate, so be cautious.